# pysftp connection to host with pem file raise exception paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType

Tags: python

I have to connect to other server in python using the pysftp library, the target server had a key value pair file (pem file), and I've got the following exception:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', [u'publickey']) (allowed_types=[u'publickey'])
```

my Code:

```
import pysftp
 pysftp.Connection(host="<IP address>", username="myUserName", password="no password", port=22, private_key="myPemFilePath.pem")
```

Please any help? and how can I fix such like this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation :

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', private_key='/path/to/keyfile') as sftp:
    #
    # ... do sftp operations
    #
```

As you can see there is no `password= "no password"`, in ther. Try, by just omitting that in your code, as it probably triggers the use of username/password authentication, skipping your private_key.

Comment: how to connect without pem file in AWS lambda?